# Solr: ComplexPhraseQueryParser ignores maxBooleanClauses value in solrconfig.xml

Tags: solr, solr4

I try to use the Solr ComplexPhraseQueryParser to enable phrase queries with wildcards at the end,
mainly to get an auto completion feature working.

So basically an input of

```
"how to t"
```

should bring up suggests like

```
"how to test the network performance"
"how to transfer data lorem ipsum"
"how to temporary lorem ipsum"
```

and so on.

I am using Solr 4.8.1.

However, when I execute the following query

```
select?q={!complexphrase}text_all_phrase:"how+to+te*"&wt=json&indent=true
```

no matter if

```
inorder= true
```

or

```
inorder=false
```

I keep getting the error null:org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024 (s. full stack below)
So I googled and found out I have to turn up the config value

```
maxBooleanClauses
```

in solrconfig.xml.
So I set it from 1024 to 4096.

Now the strange things begin:
No matter to what I set that value, the error keeps showing me 1024 as set value and of course also keeps occuring.

Has anyone else had this problem? 
Am I setting the wrong config value?
Do I have to define it somehere else too? I found something about Lucene config value for that but cannot find it.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Please do not give me any hints how to solve that autocompletion differently, we already have highlighting, suggests and facets and as all of this is not enough for our customer we really want to get it going with the ComplexPhraseQueryParser.

Thanks a lot,

Markus

EDIT
I just saw that the value I change is in the query section of the solrconfig.xml.
Is that correct? Do I have to define an own section for the ComplexPhraseQueryParser?

---

Some more info:

This is the field I am trying to search in from schema.xml:

```
  <field name="text_all_phrase"             type="text_std_token"    indexed="true"   stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"   />
```

This is the data type we set up for that field:

```
 <fieldType name="text_std_token" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">      

    <tokenizer  class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[\\.,!;?:\&quot;]+" replacement="" />
    <filter     class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">        
    <tokenizer  class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[\\.,!;?:\&quot;]+" replacement="" />
    <filter     class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And this is the full stack of the error:

```
null:org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024
at org.apache.lucene.search.ScoringRewrite$1.checkMaxClauseCount(ScoringRewrite.java:72)
at org.apache.lucene.search.ScoringRewrite$ParallelArraysTermCollector.collect(ScoringRewrite.java:149)
at org.apache.lucene.search.TermCollectingRewrite.collectTerms(TermCollectingRewrite.java:79)
at org.apache.lucene.search.ScoringRewrite.rewrite(ScoringRewrite.java:105)
at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQuery.rewrite(MultiTermQuery.java:288)
at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.complexPhrase.ComplexPhraseQueryParser$ComplexPhraseQuery.rewrite(ComplexPhraseQueryParser.java:275)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.rewrite(IndexSearcher.java:636)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.createNormalizedWeight(IndexSearcher.java:683)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:297)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1609)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1397)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:478)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:461)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:218)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1952)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:774)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:193)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the problem, seems like it was just a bug in Solr version 4.8.1,
I upgraded to Solr 4.10.1 and now it at least accepts my config value, 
even though I still have not solved all my problems at least that problem is gone.